# Using FileChooser in Codename One

Tags: codenameone

I am trying to use FileChooser in cn1.
I have followed the instructions here:

[Codename One](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/native-file-open-dialogs.html)

and

[GitHub](https://github.com/shannah/cn1-filechooser)

I added the extension and then refreshed my cn1libs

Once this was done I added the code sample to my code but it underlines the word FileChooser in red and gives me the error that it cannot find symbol.
When I hover over the line it asks if I want to create a field called FileChooser

Normally when I add a new lib it will automatically import it - but I do not see an import statement at the top of my code. Perhaps I need the import? If so please can someone give me the path as I do not know whereabouts the actual lib resides?
Any advice is appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check in your project `lib` folder to ensure the `CNFileChooser.cn1lib` exists. 
If it does exist, `clean and build` your project to see if this will fix the import.

You could also try `Ctrl+Shift+i` to fix import on Windows Netbeans or `Cmd+Shift+i` on Mac Netbeans.

Before you do `Refresh cn1lib files`, make sure your code is error-free (i.e no red underline). Comment out erroneous codes and uncomment them after the refresh.

Be sure to import `com.codename1.ext.filechooser.FileChooser` and not `javafx.stage.FileChooser`.

If the problem persists, kindly share your operating system and IDE details here to get further assistance.